# Voltage of open circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits

> A battery with emf $\varepsilon$ and internal resistance $r$ is connected
>   with a resistor $R$ in the following open circuit. What is the voltage $V_{ab}=V_a-V_b$?
>
> [image]

The answer is $- \varepsilon$. "*No current. There is no voltage change across R and r.*". But I don't really understand why ... I was thinking intuitively it should be $0$? Then thinking of how to get 0, I was thinking ... $V_a = - \varepsilon$ since its on the negative terminal, the $V_b = + \varepsilon$ since its on the positive terminal. But $V_a - V_b = -2 \varepsilon$ ... how do I make sense of this?

Answer (score 2):

Think of the open as infinite resistance. Your current will be $I = E/(R+\infty) = 0$. Now, voltage dropping across every resistor is proportional to the current and resistance: $V(r) = I * r$. Since infinite resistance is infinitely larger than R, all $E$ will drop across $\infty$ and 0v is left to R. Particluarly, $V_R = 0\mathrm{v} * R = 0\mathrm{v}$. Meantime, $V_\infty = 0\mathrm{v} * \infty = E$. The only way to get a finite value with one of multipliers 0 is to multiply it by $\infty$. Actually, $0 * \infty$ is uncertainty. But here we know that it must be E since $V_\infty$ is the only place where all voltage, generated by supply, must be dropped.

Comment: or think of it as a capacitor in steady state :)

Answer (score 1):

> But Va−Vb=−2ε ... how do I make sense of this?

It's incorrect to write $V_a = \varepsilon$.  The voltage $\varepsilon$ is *across* the battery.

Try this:  place a ground symbol on the wire between the battery and the $a$ terminal; this is your zero node or *the place you put the black lead of your voltmeter*.

Now, if you place the red lead on the terminal of the battery connected to the resistor, you'll measure $\varepsilon$ volts.

If you place the red lead on the other side of the resistor, you'll measure $\varepsilon + V_R$ volts but $V_R = 0V$ so you still measure $\varepsilon$ volts.

But note that now you're measuring the voltage $V_{ba}$ since the read lead is connected to terminal b and the black lead is on terminal a.

So, $V_{ba} = \varepsilon = -V_{ab}$

Answer (score 0):

Ok , Potential is work done by electrostatic force as you move from A to B per Couloumb. So transfer 1 coulomb from A to B and as you move through the battery, E is directed from +ve plate to -ve plate . So work done by $\vec{E}$ is ($V_-) - (V_+$) , which means $-EMF$.

And yes that is an assumption that charge must reach the positive plate with the same velocity with which it entered the negative plate .